# Disable Cache Interceptor

Tags: caching, nestjs

Is there a possible way to disable Cache Interceptors while on development, except for putting minimum TTL for a cache?

```
@UseInterceptors(CacheInterceptor)
```

as a global, so the developer wont have to wait until the cache is cleared during development.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
@UseInterceptors(process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? function() {} : CacheInterceptor)
```

Basically, use a dummy interceptor during development so that data won't be cached